# Set CSV file's newline

Tags: python, csv, newline

I'm trying to create a newline when I write to a csv file, but it keeps giving me an error 'ValueError: illegal newline value: '. I've tried replacing 'w' with 'a'.

```
import csv

number = input("Enter student count: ")

jada = 1


for i in  number:
    student = input("Student name: ")
    value = input("Enter the deposited amount: ")
    with open('budget.csv', 'w', newline=' \n', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
        write = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["Nmr", "Name", "Deposited amount"])
        writer.writerow([jada, student, value])
        jada += 1
```

Comment: Use `newline=''`.

Comment: Yeah tried that before. Didn't work

Comment: Where you have written `newline=' \n'`, *what do you want that to mean*? What should happen when you use the code, *that is different from* the default behaviour (not specifying `newline` at all)? "I'm trying to create a newline when I write to a csv file" I don't understand. Your output file will contain newlines if you write it normally, as long as there is more than one row. That's how the CSV format determines the row boundaries.

Comment: What do you want the overall code to do? How many times should the file be opened? How many rows should be written to the file *in total*? How many times should the `["Nmr", "Name", "Deposited amount"]` row *specifically* be written? Please try to think carefully about the intended logic of the code, and make sure you can explain it, in plain English, step by step.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to csv. Only written txt files. Trying to learn new stuff. I used a tutorial online for this and wasn't expecting an error like this. Thank You!

Comment: @JanAlarAlesmaa Your last comment said "Thank You".  Is your problem solved now?  If so, you can add the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `ValueError: illegal newline value:` because your newline has a space at the beginning,  `\n`.

But if you're trying to force a particular newline, that won't have any effect.  You need to use the `lineterminator`[^1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) option when creating the writer:

```py
writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator="\n")
```

And the CSV docs specifically recommend using `newline=""`[^2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`

So your code should look more like this:

```py
with open("budget.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator="\n")
```